# Magento 2 Checkout Missing Postcode

Tags: magento, magento2

I recently discovered the site I am developing in Magento 2 is missing the Postcode field in the Shipping Address form on the checkout page. I have been digging around and cannot find any reason why it is missing. I found [this bug](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1522) someone opened with Magento but the solution mentioned does not work for me. The results I am seeing are the same though.

On `/checkout/` in the Shipping tab the Postcode field is missing. But I am able to continue to the next step. However when I try to complete the checkout I get the error `An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.` which I believe is because the address has no zip code. This is while checking out as a guest. I have tested checking out as a customer who already has an address saved and that lets me complete the checkout.

I have disabled all modules and returned to using the Luma theme for testing and I am seeing the same results. Unfortunately upgrading to 2.2 isn't an option at the moment as we are dangerously close to launch so we will have to update after launch. So I don't know if that update will fix this issue or not.

Magento CE 2.1.8

PHP 7.0.24

If anyone has any guidance or suggestions on how to find my missing field I would greatly appreciate it.

**EDIT**

The Phone number field is missing as well. While that isn't as much of a concern, it is probably missing for the same reason.

Also, I just realized that the data migration from our old site (1.9.3) seems to have caused the issue. I tested our new site with a DB before and after the migration and that is what caused us to lose the postcode field. Our data migration only contains Sales data and Customers - no products or categories. I'm digging in now to see what would have caused it. I have tried a reindex multiple times and that didn't solve it.

Comment: Have you tried to apply the patch at the bottom of the bug report? https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/304c734ae9044aaec6a450d94b7e7f7be69c8ea9

Comment: @Joe Yes I tried the changes in that PR with no luck. Those changes are just DOB validation changes, so I'm not sure why they were attached to that bug report.

Comment: Does the html for the Zip/Phone fields render? (when you view source/inspect-element -- is the html there?) If so, then it's just css that's hiding it and you can add a rule to force it to display. Won't fix the root of the issue, but maybe it can get you by until you have it all figured out.

Comment: Also, are there any js errors in your console? Anything in system.log or exception.log as well?

Comment: @Joe The html is not rendered. The form is built out with Knockout it looks like, and that field is not built out. So Knockout doesn't see it as a field to render for some reason. No console errors or anything relevant in the Magento logs for that matter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity, when I posted this I thought it was a programming issue, but you are correct the end result was not a programming issue. I don't have enough reputation to close it myself.

Comment: @rain2o - No trouble. Just to be clear though - a question isn't about programming if there **might** be a programming-related answer. The question itself **must** explicitly be about programming. I can't see that in your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well I found the culprit. When we ran our data migration it seems that the tables `eav_form_element` and `customer_form_attribute` lost some information during the migration. The attributes got a little shuffled up. The quick fix was to add in the missing postcode and phone number fields into the appropriate tables. I still need to go back and figure out where I went wrong in the migration configuration.

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted. Were you able to figure out what was an issue with migration mapping?

Comment: @TimBezhashvyly I honestly don't remember anymore, but probably not. Unfortunately that project was a rush project and we had to move on to other thing as soon as it was done.

Comment: This was exactly the issue and fixed our problem. Does anyone know how these get set initially or if there's a way to fix/update without directly updating the db?

Answer (score 0):

Run these two queries into database, will fix the problem.

```
  INSERT INTO `customer_form_attribute` (`form_code`, `attribute_id`) VALUES 
   ('adminhtml_customer_address', '33'), ('customer_address_edit', '33'), 
   ('customer_register_address', '33'), ('adminhtml_customer_address', '34'), 
   ('customer_address_edit', '34'), ('customer_register_address', '34');


  INSERT INTO `eav_form_element` (`element_id`, `type_id`, `fieldset_id`, 
   `attribute_id`, `sort_order`) VALUES (NULL, '1', NULL, '33', '7'), (NULL, '2', 
    NULL,'33', '7'),(NULL, '3', NULL, '33', '6'), (NULL, '4', NULL, '33', '6'),
    (NULL, '1',NULL, '34', '9'), (NULL, '2', NULL, '34', '9'),
    (NULL, '3', NULL, '34', '8'), (NULL,'4', NULL, '34', '8');
```

after that run deploy command

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

hope this will help you to fix the issue

Happy Coding !!